# Load html body innerHTML using Selenium

Tags: html, excel, vba, selenium, html-tbody

I am searching for a way to load the HTML body into selenium bot

```
html.body.innerHTML = .responseText

'
Set bot = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
bot.Get HERE
```

Is it possible to do such a task or I have to save the html body to a file then navigate to that file?

I could manage that by exporting the html body to a file using this procedure

```
Sub ExportHTML(sInput As String)
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Charset = "UTF-8"
        .Open
        .WriteText sInput
        .SaveToFile Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\OutputHTML.html", 2
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

After that I could load the file using the selenium driver like that

```
bot.Get "file:///" & Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\OutputHTML.html"
```

Comment: Possibly use execute_script (JavaScript) to generate a element with an unique id and load the html to that? You'd lose it once page refreshed. Not entirely sure why you would want to do this though?

Comment: Thanks, my tutor. Dealing with the website is quite easier with xmlhttp than selenium and faster but I needed to use selenium so as to take a screenshot of a table. So I thought of using the HTML body (the response) to do such a trick. Can you provide me with the way of using exceutescript?

Answer (score 1):

You can't load the HTML body seperately as the HTML Document in it's core form consists of two manadatory parts:

- The *`<head>`*
- The *`<body>`*

Example of a simple HTML document:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I already used xmlhttp to get the html body in sepcific way (including credentials) but I needed to take screen shot so I thought of loading the html body to a browser through selenium. It works only if I save the html body to a file

Comment: Then possibly you are loading the xml but not the html?

Comment: No, I got the html and I have tested that by exporting the html body (the response) to a file. I have updated the question and added the code that enables me to export the response.

Comment: Possibly that's the only way you should do it.